# Как вывести данные из столбца?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть несколько записей, под каждой кнопка, одна и таже. Жмём кнопку под любой записью, выводится колонка `more` именно для этой записи.

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на кнопку, для каждой записи выводилась своя запись из `more`? Сейчас выводится только первая.

```
// Вывод записей из БД
<?
  $types = typeClass();
  $list = $DB->getAll('SELECT * FROM `list` ORDER BY `id`');
  foreach($list As $l){
?>
<div class="day">
    <div class="date"><?=$l['date']?></div>
    <div class="time"><?=$l['time']?></div>

    <div class="kitchen <?=$l['type']?>">
        <?=$types[$l['type']]?>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <?=$l['text']?>
    </div>
    <a class="button more" href="#"><span>Подробнее</span></a>
</div>
<?
}
?>

// Код кнопки
<div class="popup more">
<?
  global $DB;
  $dataSql = $DB->getAll('SELECT `more` FROM `list` ORDER BY `id`');
  foreach($dataSql As $sql){
?>
<div class="form" name="list[list][<?=$sql['id']?>][more]"><?=$sql['more']?></div>
<?             
  }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант первый. В атрибут `data` кнопки добавляем текст `more` и затем выводим в попап окне:

```js
$(function() {
 $('.more').click(function(){
    var more = $(this).attr("data");
    $(".form").html(more); 
  $('.popup').fadeIn(300); 
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<?
  $types = typeClass();
  $list = $DB->getAll('SELECT * FROM `list` ORDER BY `id`');
  foreach($list As $l){
?>
<div class="day">
    <div class="date"><?=$l['date']?></div>
    <div class="time"><?=$l['time']?></div>

    <div class="kitchen <?=$l['type']?>">
        <?=$types[$l['type']]?>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <?=$l['text']?>
    </div>
    <a class="button more" href="#" data="<?=$l['more']?>"><span>Подробнее</span></a>
</div>
<?
}
?>

// Код кнопки
<div class="popup more">
<div class="form" name=""></div>
</div>
```

Вариант второй. В атрибут `data` добавляем `id` записи и каждому попап окну добавляем идентификатор записи и при нажатии на `Подробнее` показиваем окно попап которое соответствует `id`:

```js
$(function() {
 $('.more').click(function(){
    var more = $(this).attr("data");
  $(more).fadeIn(300); 
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<?
  $types = typeClass();
  $list = $DB->getAll('SELECT * FROM `list` ORDER BY `id`');
  foreach($list As $l){
?>
<div class="day">
    <div class="date"><?=$l['date']?></div>
    <div class="time"><?=$l['time']?></div>

    <div class="kitchen <?=$l['type']?>">
        <?=$types[$l['type']]?>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <?=$l['text']?>
    </div>
    <a class="button more" href="#" data="#<?= $l['id'] ?>"><span>Подробнее</span></a>
</div>
<?
}
?>

// Код кнопки

<?
  global $DB;
  $dataSql = $DB->getAll('SELECT `id`,`more`  FROM `list` ORDER BY `id`');
  foreach($dataSql As $sql){
?>
<div class="popup more" id="<?= $sql['id'] ?>">
<div class="form" name="list[list][<?=$sql['id']?>][more]"><?=$sql['more']?></div>
</div>
<?             
  }
?>
```

Comment: второй вариант почему то выводит информацию для всех сразу

Comment: Вместо `<a class="button more" href="#" data="#<?=$sql['id']?>"><span>Подробнее</span></a>` нужно `<a class="button more" href="#" data="#<?= $l['id'] ?>"><span>Подробнее</span></a>` Внес правки в ответ